# Need to fetch data from file having comma and Pipedelimited

Tags: unix

We have a requirement to create a file having below information:

Source file looks like (Detail.txt)

```
Seq,Flag,Messages  
1000,1,Msg 1 | Msg 2 |Msg 3 |  
1002,0,Msg 4 | Msg 5 |
```

Need to transform the file in below format
Target file should look like:

```
Seq ,Flag,Messages  
1000,1,Msg 1  
1000,1,Msg 2  
1000,1,Msg 3  
1002,0,Msg 4  
1002,0,Msg 5
```

Appreciate if anyone help us on above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
> cat swapnil.txt
Seq,Flag,Messages
1000,1,Msg 1 | Msg 2 |Msg 3 |
1002,0,Msg 4 | Msg 5 |
> perl -F,  -lane ' { print if $.==1; if ($.>1) { @x=split(/\|/,$F[2]);for (@x[0..$#x-1]) { s/^\s*//g; print "$F[0],$F[1],$_" }}}' swapnil.txt
Seq,Flag,Messages
1000,1,Msg 1
1000,1,Msg 2
1000,1,Msg 3
1002,0,Msg 4
1002,0,Msg 5
>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. It helped!!